# Assert on Custom Error Messaging in Jest Tests?

Tags: javascript, express, jestjs, ts-jest, node.js-got

Is it possible to assert on custom error messages when using the `got` library in your tests? `Got` will throw an error if the response is >= 400, so I can assert on a the response code (via the string got returns), but not my own custom error messages.

```
  it('Responds with a 404 if not found', async () => {
    const paramA = 'a param that will make my function fail';

    try {
      await got(
        `http://localhost:${port}/myEndpointName/${paramA}`,
      );
    } catch (error) {
      // Would Like to assert on this statement below
      // expect(error.message).toEqual("A custom error message of my selection");

      // But instead I have to assert on this
      expect(error.message).toEqual("Response code 404 (Not Found)");
    }
  });

    export const doStuff: RequestHandler = async function (req, res, next) {
      const { paramA } = req.params;
    
      try {
        const stuffFromElsewhere: NPMPackage = await got(
          `https://someothersite.com/${paramA}`,
        ).json();
            
        return res.status(200).json({ paramA, "good job" });
      } catch (error) {
        return res.status(404).json({ message: 'A custom error message of my selection' });
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is a common http error, it has been thrown by `got` not by your server logic.

If you want to assert the response error message, let's try:

```
expect(error.response.body.message).toEqual("A custom error message of my selection");
```

Comment: That assertion fails because error.response.body.message is undefined in my test.

Comment: Ah it wasn't working with my IDE debugger but console.warn helped - thanks for the tip. Solution is to do JSON.parse(resError.response.body)['message']

Comment: @stk1234 Try to call `. json()`  for `got` action.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to assert on `JSON.parse(resError.response.body)['message']`